# Al probar la API en postman aparece error 404, Spring boot, Postgresql

Tags: java, api, postgresql, spring-boot, rest

Al probar la api que realicé en *spring-boot* me arroja error 404, ya verifiqué nombres y el puerto y no sé por qué pueda ser el error.

No sé si en application.Properties es necesario poner más líneas de código.

La conexión a la bd se ha establecido.

Los nombres están correctos, si alguien sabe qué pueda generar ese error se lo agradecería, gracias.

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/PruebaOLJ
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123
database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.sql.init.continue-on-error=true
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=900000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=150
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

**Controlador**

```
package rest;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import model.Person;
import service.PersonService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping ("/person/")
public class PersonRest {
    
    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;
    
    @GetMapping ("returnall/")
    private ResponseEntity<List<Person>> getAllPerson (){
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok(personService.findAll());
    }

}
```

**Servicio**

```
@Service
public class PersonService implements PersonRepository {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    
    @Override
    public List<Person> findAll() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya revisé nombres, protocolo, puerto y no sé que pueda más pueda generar el error

Comment: Curiosidad: en `PersonService`, en tu código la primera línea debería ser `@Service` y no Service. ¿Es un error al copiar? ¿Se muestran errores en la consola?

Comment: Fue error al copiar, en consola no aparece ningún error

Comment: ¿Estás usando Spring Data?. `PersonService` no debería implementar `PersonRepository`. Subí el código de `PersonRepository`. En el application.properties deshabilita el `continue-on-error` que puede estar ocultando algún problema.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es la ruta del método `getAllPerson`. Deberías reemplazar `returnall/` por `/returnall`

Te quedaría de esta forma:

```
    @GetMapping ("/returnall")
    private ResponseEntity<List<Person>> getAllPerson (){ 
        return ResponseEntity.ok(personService.findAll());
    }
```

Aunque no es estrictamente necesario, también se podría cambiar la ruta del controller de la siguiente forma:

```
@RequestMapping ("/person")
```

De todas formas creo que podrías considerar reemplazar `returnall` por vacío, de modo que tu servicio responda a `http://localhost:8080/person` con la lista de todas las personas. Para esto deberías reemplazar

```
        @GetMapping ("/returnall")
```

por

```
        @GetMapping
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné. En mi caso fue que no me fijé que en el controlador había colocado como anotación al principio @Controller, cuando lo correcto es @RestController. Lo corregí y al probar en postman ya funcionó.